# Error: curl_easy_setopt: 48 @ Downloads.Curl

Tags: julia

I am downloading Flux.jl through the REPL in VS Code in a newly created environment. When I added the package via the package manager, I got a a bunch of errors as shown below:

```
┌ Error: curl_easy_setopt: 48
└ @ Downloads.Curl /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Downloads/src/Curl/utils.jl:36
┌ Error: curl_easy_setopt: 48
└ @ Downloads.Curl /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Downloads/src/Curl/utils.jl:36
└ @ Downloads.Curl /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Downloads/src/Curl/utils.jl:36
```

This happened probably 100 times but it still seems like the package installed correctly. Is there anything further I need to do here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See https://github.com/JuliaLang/Downloads.jl/issues/149. The fix will be included in the upcoming Julia 1.6.4 and Julia 1.7.0 releases.
(The error is caused by a change in macOS Monterey, which resulted in Julia finding and loading the wrong dynamic libraries.)

> This happened probably 100 times but it still seems like the package
> installed correctly. Is there anything further I need to do here?

Probably not; Julia package manager falls back to installing packages from git if https download fails.